# Cannot find UIDocumentPickerViewController in scope

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am completely new to iOS or Mac development, and I am trying to implement opening and reading files in an app for MacOS. By default I had my app use SwiftUI. Looking up how to implement such a functionality using SwiftUI I saw suggestions to use `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. However I cannot find a proper documentation as to how to use it in practice. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) page is not informative at all -- it doesn't provide any information as of how to actually use this class.

Trying to follow some examples I found elsewhere on the Internet, I am now stuck with getting `Cannot find UIDocumentPickerViewController in scope` compilation error. I have tried importing `UIKit`, `AppKit`, `CoreServices`, `MobileCoreServices`, `Cocoa` but nothing seems to help -- extending the class as described in [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56645819/how-to-open-file-dialog-with-swiftui-on-platform-uikit-for-mac) just fails with the same compilation error.

How do I properly use UIDocumentPickerViewController, or how do I implement the same functionality using some other method if this one is wrong?

Comment: UIDocumentPickerViewController is for iOS.

Comment: @matt Thank you for your answer. Could you suggest what would be the alternative I should use for the Mac app?

Comment: @saferif There is no document picker other than  NSOpenPanel for macOS AFAIK

Comment: Use to do what? I do not know what you are trying to do. If the idea is to let the user pick a file to open, that is an NSOpenPanel. But really I'm totally in the dark as to your intentions.

Comment: Looks like `NSOpenPanel` is a way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `UIDocumentPickerViewController` is not available when building for Mac OS X, and `NSOpenPanel` seems to be a way to get the necessary functionality.